# how can I modify binfmt_misc kernel module to make postscript files system executeable?

Tags: command-line, kernel, scripts, postscript

I begin all my scripts with %!PS, and I am wondering what I can do to make the scripts system executable. So far i have been runing everything from the ghostscript terminal. I tried making the files executeable, but it results in errors amounting to the script being run line by line, and being missinterpreted.

Heres a simple source:

```
%!PS
/Times findfont 72 scalefont setfont
306 396 translate % move center to here

4{
         2 2 moveto
        90 rotate
        (H@x0rz) true charpath stroke

}repeat
showpage
```

and here are the errors that follow when trying to run it.

```
$ ./rotate.ps 
./rotate.ps: line 1: fg: no job control
./rotate.ps: line 2: /Times: No such file or directory
./rotate.ps: line 3: 306: command not found
./rotate.ps: line 5: 4{: command not found
./rotate.ps: line 6: 2: command not found
./rotate.ps: line 7: 90: command not found
./rotate.ps: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `true'
./rotate.ps: line 8: `  (H@x0rz) true charpath stroke'
```

how can I make my postscript files system executable.
using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 or later.

EDIT trying to use binfmt-misc::

OK so I am looking at setting up binfmt-misc to execute the postcript, but I am not sure how to set it up.
In

```
#/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc$ ls
register  status
```

the status file says enabled, 
and the register file is blank.

on the binfmt-misc wiki page I see some examples, but I also see a reference to a "TYPE CODE"
and i do not know what that is for postscript.

I tried adding 
 GS:M:MZ::/home/user/bin/gs
 to register, via vim and echo but I got read and write errors even as root, and now I get permission denied when I try to edit the register file.

```
 root@xy:/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc# echo 'GS:M:MZ::/home/user/bin/gs'  > register  
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

Admitadly, I have no clue what I am doing.

I also tried putting a shebang with the ghostscript path at the first line of my script, and that comes back with ghostscript having an unrecoverable error, 
it loads a window that immediately closes. Im not sure what to do.

the websites I have been reading are:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc

Comment: If Ghostscript doesn't like shebangs, use binfmt: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401808/70524

Comment: ok, that might work, provided I can figure out how to set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting the example from [the linked U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401808/70524) works fine enough for me:

```
$ echo ':postscript:M::%!PS::/usr/bin/gs:'  | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
:postscript:M::%!PS::/usr/bin/gs:
$ cat > foo.ps
%!PS
/Times findfont 72 scalefont setfont
306 396 translate % move center to here

4{
         2 2 moveto
        90 rotate
        (H@x0rz) true charpath stroke

}repeat
showpage
$ chmod +x foo.ps
$ ./foo.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Querying operating system for font files...
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/Resource/Font/Times.
Can't find (or can't open) font file Times.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 4646060 3103684 11124488 9679005 1 done.
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

Opens up a ps file with `H@x0rz` written in various orientations.

Comment: Every time I run that first command, I get "bash: !PS: event not found" I suspect the % sign

Comment: Did you use single quotes? History expansion doesn't happen in single quotes iirc, like in the command shown above.

Comment: i did use single quotes then, I tried opening the file in root, with vi, and I get E667 fsync failed. I have a file named postscript in the /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc folder now....

Comment: ok its working now. I dont know what those errors and warnings were about. maybe I should have reloaded the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *Horrible Hack (TM)* that solves your original problem without binfmt. I know that this is not exactly answering the edited question, but I remembered having hacked together something similar for C files in my irresponsible youth, so here it goes.

You can put the following prefix into your PS file and make it executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk !/^#!/ { print >> ".tmp.ps" } END { system("/usr/bin/ghostscript .tmp.ps ; rm .tmp.ps ") }
```

This runs the entire script through awk, removes all lines starting with '#!' (i.e. the first one), pipes the result into a tmpfile, and runs that through ghostscript.